# Scrapy spider returns 200 response after a few mintues

Tags: scrapy, splash-screen

I have issues with dynamic content when I tried to scrap a website. I just used Docker to add Splash to my Scrapy using the following:

https://blog.scrapinghub.com/2015/03/02/handling-javascript-in-scrapy-with-splash/

Unfortunately, I am still not capturing content because of dynamic content (possibly?).

My code runs, captures content, then after scraping around 4000 pages, it just returns this error for the next 6000 pages, most of which have data:

```
[scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://www...> (referer: None)
```

Here is my spider code:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy_splash import SplashRequest

class PeopleSpider(scrapy.Spider):
 name="people"
 start_urls=[
  'http://www.canada411.ca/res/%s/' % page for page in xrange(5192080000,5192090000)   
 ]
 def start_requests(self):
  for url in self.start_urls:
    yield SplashRequest(url, self.parse,
     endpoint='render.html',
     args={'wait': 2},
    )
 def parse(self,response):
  for people in response.css('div#contact'):
   yield{
    'name': people.css('h1.vcard__name::text').extract_first().strip().title(),
    'address': people.css('div.vcard__address::text').extract_first().strip().split(',')[0].strip(),
    'city': people.css('div.vcard__address::text').extract_first().strip().split(',')[1].strip().split(' ')[0].strip(),
    'province': people.css('div.vcard__address::text').extract_first().strip().split(',')[1].strip().split(' ')[1].strip(),
    'postal code': people.css('div.vcard__address::text').extract_first().split(',')[2].strip().replace(' ',''),
    'phone': people.css('span.vcard__label::text').extract_first().replace('(','').replace(')','').replace('-','').replace(' ',''),
   }
```

[image]

Comment: Maybe the site you are scraping has started showing captchas

Comment: Interesting, any solutions for this?

Comment: I cannot post code/solution, I can suggest you to save HTML of response in a file when you are not getting data, and then open that HTML file in browser to see why name, address etc does not exists on that page

Comment: I did: if not response.meta.get('solve_captcha',False): print "CAPTCHA", and you are right, it is a CAPTCHA problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Save HTML of response in a file when you are not getting data, and then open that HTML file in browser to see why `name`, `address` etc does not exists on that page.

I suspect they are showing Captcha due to continuous requests from same IP.

If they are showing captcha, you can use proxy services to avoid captchas,

Also create a [DownloadMiddleware](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/downloader-middleware.html) and inside [process_request](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/downloader-middleware.html#scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.DownloaderMiddleware.process_request) function, check if there is captcha, then scrape that link again with `dont_filter=True` parameter.

**EDIT**

You can write to a file using this code, BTW just google and you will find bunch of ways to write to file using Python.

```
with open('response.html', '2+') as the_file:
     the_file.write(response.body)
```